# How to strongly type the return type of a function based on a particular member of a Discriminated Union?

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

Let me start by saying I know I could use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) but they offer no real type safety in the implementation so I would rather avoid them.

I have a function that a few params one of which is a [Discriminated Union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) and most of the time returns a non null result except for in some cases with a particular member of the union. I've gotten sick of using type guards all over the code when I know the result will not be non null because at that location I know the union member being passed in and would like to improve the typing so this isn't required.

I have tried multiple combinations of [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) and [Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) without luck. Generics seem to mess up type narrowing among other problems. Part of my problem has been figuring out how to leverage the discriminating property within the objects as most examples use a parameter directly for conditional return types.

Example of one attempt:

```
interface InsertAction {
    type: 'insert';
    index: number;
}

interface RemoveAction {
    type: 'remove';
    index: number;
}

type Action = InsertAction | RemoveAction;

function ensureUnreachable(value: never, message?: string): never {
  throw new Error(message || `Unreachable code hit with value ${String(value)}`);
}

type TransformResult<T> =
    T extends InsertAction ? number :
    T extends RemoveAction ? number | null : never;

function transform<T extends Action>(index: number, op: T): TransformResult<T> {
    switch (op.type) {
        case 'insert':
            return op.index <= index ? index + 1 : index;
        case 'remove':
            return op.index === index ? null : op.index < index ? index - 1 : index;
        default:
            ensureUnreachable(op);
    }
}

// Type should be number
const alwaysNotNull = transform(5, { type: 'insert', index: 2});
// Type could be null
const maybeNull = transform(5, { type: 'remove', index: 2});

const unknownAction: Action = { type: 'insert', index: 5};
const alsoMaybeNull = transform(5, unknownAction);
```

Comment: Based on this [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) I would say such kind of type narrowing is not currently supported.

Comment: That is very possible. It would be nice if there was a way to have conditional return types without generics. Or if function overloads actually enforced type safety.